# Read shadowed private field of the outer class

Tags: javascript, private, ecmascript-2021

I expected that being inside of class `B` I can read private fields `#a` and `#x` of class `A`. But in fact I can read only `#a`, in case of access to `#x` I get an error:

> Cannot read private member #x from an object whose class did not declare it

Seems like `#x` of class `B` shadows similar field of `A`. First of all it seems illogical - why does it work in such way and if it is intentional, way was it planned in such way? And is it possible to read `#x` on `A` instance being inside of `B`?

```js
class A {
  #a = "A#a"
  #x = "A#x"

  static B = class B {
    #b = "B#b"
    #x = "B#x"

    static doSmth(obj) {
      try { console.log(obj.#a) } catch (e) { console.log(e.message) }
      try { console.log(obj.#b) } catch (e) { console.log(e.message) }
      try { console.log(obj.#x) } catch (e) { console.log(e.message) }
    }
  }
}

console.log("=== A ===")
A.B.doSmth(new A)
console.log("")
console.log("=== B ===")
A.B.doSmth(new A.B)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100vh }
.as-console-row.as-console-row:after { content: none }
```

I'm using Google Chrome 89.0.4389.90 if it matters.

PS: [Same question in Russian.](//ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1257011/178988)

Answer (score 1):

Give a part from [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/Private_class_fields)

> Like their public equivalent, private static methods are called on the
> class itself, not instances of the class. Like private static fields,
> they are only accessible from inside the class declaration.

You pass **A** into **B** method doSmth

```
A.B.doSmth(new A)

A#a
Cannot read private member #b from an object whose class did not declare it
Cannot read private member #x from an object whose class did not declare it
```

Method have no access A#x since B#x also declared and A have no access to it.

Next you pass **B** into **B** method doSmth

```
A.B.doSmth(new A.B)

Cannot read private member #a from an object whose class did not declare it
B#b
B#x
```

Method B have no acess to A#а

```js
class A {
  #a = "A#a"
  #b = "A#b"
  #x = "A#x"
  
  static doSmthA(obj) {
      try { console.log(obj.#a) } catch (e) { console.log(e.message) }
      try { console.log(obj.#b) } catch (e) { console.log(e.message) }
      try { console.log(obj.#x) } catch (e) { console.log(e.message) }
  }

  static B = class B {
    
    #a = "B#a"
    #b = "B#b"
    #x = "B#x"

    static doSmthB(obj) {
      try { console.log(obj.#a) } catch (e) { console.log(e.message) }
      try { console.log(obj.#b) } catch (e) { console.log(e.message) }
      try { console.log(obj.#x) } catch (e) { console.log(e.message) }
    }
  }
}

console.log("=== A ===")
A.doSmthA(new A)
console.log("")
console.log("=== B ===")
A.B.doSmthB(new A.B)

console.log("=== NEXT ===")

console.log("=== A ===")
A.doSmthA(new A.B)
console.log("")
console.log("=== B ===")
A.B.doSmthB(new A)
```